# How to take Jenkins master node offline using CLI?

Tags: command-line, jenkins

I have been manually taking the master (and only) node offline whenever I sync our development database to avoid a bunch of false test failures. I have a script that does the full DB import and would like to automate the node maintenance as well.

How can I mark the master node temporarily offline using the command-line interface JAR?

- I wrote a simple Bash script to execute Jenkins tasks.
- I can authenticate using that script.

  ```
  $ jenkins who-am-i
  Authenticated as: david
  Authorities:
    david
    authenticated
  ```
- However, I cannot get `offline-node` or `online-node` to recognize the master node. The help states that I can omit the node name for "master", but that doesn't work.

  ```
  $ jenkins offline-node
  Argument "NAME" is required
  java -jar jenkins-cli.jar online-node NAME
  Stop using a node for performing builds temporarily, until the next "online-node" command.
   NAME                : Slave name, or empty string for master
  ```

  It seems to be looking specifically for a slave, but I need to take the master's executor offline.

  ```
  $ jenkins offline-node master
  No such slave "master" exists. Did you mean "null"?
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have one build executor on the master and no standalone build nodes, use this command instead:

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar quiet-down
```

This will stop any new builds from executing.  You can use

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar cancel-quiet-down
```

to put Jenkins back on line; at this point it will run any builds that were queued up while it was offline.

Answer (score 6):

It's not exactly intuitive, but the Jenkins documentation is correct. If you want to specify the master node for `offline-node` or `online-node`, use the empty string:

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar offline-node ""
```

That said, you should probably use @gareth_bowles answer anyways in case you add slaves in the future.

Comment: That's something I never knew !