# jenkins change label as requested

Tags: jenkins, automation

We use jenkins for automation for our test infrastructure. The requirement is to give users the ability to use a jenkins node for their private test or debug using private jenkins jobs and then put back in the pool of nodes marked with labels; so that other jobs that were marked to run on particular labels can be run without interference.

We can achieve this by letting users alter label, but that didnt workout as users (nearly 50) are making their own label names and it takes time for admin to reassign the nodes (even with process) and precious test time is getting affected.

we are looking for some solution such as ability to provide buttons like take this node offline (cant use this option since jenkins cannot see the node anymore and so users cannot run jenkins job on the node) but may be with the ability to run scripts.

I have done some research on this but have to compromise on some requirements, so i decided to seek help from the community... SUGGESTIONS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you have a look to this question:

[How to take Jenkins master node offline using CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20577994/how-to-take-jenkins-master-node-offline-using-cli)

In the 1st question, there are some CLI to make a node offline.

Maybe you can create a dedicated job on the master with one parameter (the node name). This job will call the Jenkins CLI to stop your node.

Comment: I agree with Bruno, Mark Node offline is a lightweight operation, it won't interrupt current jobs, it won't even break the slave connection, just prevent it from running any jobs. Looks like it should fit the initial task.

Comment: But if I put it offline, I cannot let users run their Jenkins  jobs as I explained. Right ? But yes seems like a job to perform seems like a good option.