# How to identify admins on Jenkins using groovy scripts

Tags: groovy, jenkins, automation, jenkins-plugins

I want to be able to check whether the current build user who is running the job is admin or not. I used some APIs to figure out the admins user list as shown below

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
import hudson.model.User
import hudson.security.Permission

allUsers = User.getAll()
adminList = []
for (u in allUsers) {
 if (u.hasPermission(Jenkins.ADMINISTER)) {
 // if (u.canDelete()) {
   adminList.add(u)
  }
}
println allUsers 
println adminList
```

but always both the list of users (admins and average-joes) are same, yes i am sure, not all users are admin in my jenkins server :)

Comment: Your problem is what if your build is triggered by (for example) a scm change? I think the admin is more for configuring jobs. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: i have to be able to tackle these [issue1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28972393/jenkins-slave-api-setlabelstring-adds-to-user-list) and  [issue2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28819435/jenkins-change-label-as-requested), so i need to allow admins to change any label by running the job, where as other users can change only their labelled nodes by running the job, hope i was clear !

Answer (score 0):

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
import hudson.model.User

allUsers = User.getAll()
adminList = []
authStrategy = Jenkins.instance.getAuthorizationStrategy()

for (u in allUsers) {
    if (authStrategy.hasPermission(u.toString(), Jenkins.ADMINISTER)) {
        adminList.add(u)
    }
}

println(adminList)
```

Comment: You should use `u.id`instead of `u.toString()`